# sql select - get 10 records from id xxx

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have `database` rows `ordered` by `id`

I want to select `10` of them starting by id `n`

10 next records can be easily achieved with using LIMIT

I have problem with that `id` thing. Do I have to select row WHERE `id` is `n`, get its position and then use OFFSET? Or is there something more effective?

What would the query look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET n;
```

or if you have `id` then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id >= n
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try with `WHERE id >= n` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rownum` to select 10 records with `id >= n`:

```
select * from table where id >= n and rownum <=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select *
from table
where id >= n
order by id asc
limit 10
```

id >= n => select from  n

order by id asc => make sure they are ordered properly

limit 10 => first 10

Answer (score 1):

use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id >= n
LIMIT 10
```